Number of Multiset Pemutations with a Given Property
For a multiset with $n_1$ 1's, $n_2$ 2's, ..., and $n_k$ $k$'s, the total number of multiset permutations is
$$
\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_k!}.
$$
where $n=n_1+\cdots+n_k$.  Out of this set, some permutations dominate their reverse.
For example, when $n_1=2$ and $n_2=2$, we have 6 permutations
(1122), (1212), (1221), (2112), (2121), (2211).  The last 2 permutations dominate their reverse (1212) and (1122).  The first 4 do not.
My questions are:
(1) For given $n_1$ to $n_k$, what is the number of multiset permutations that do not dominate their reverse.
(2) How do we enumerate this subset?
I can of course enumerate the entire set and eliminate those that dominate their reverse, but I am hoping that there is an explicit formula for computing the number of permutations that satisfy this property.

Could you clarify what you mean by "dominate"?

By dominate, I mean lexicographically.  (2121) dominates its reverse (1212), but (1122) does not dominate its reverse (2211).  Also (1221) is the same as its reverse (1221), so it also does not dominate its reverse.

An interesting and related question is: How many palindromic multiset permutations are there? (Palindromic meaning equal to its own reverse.) If we know $N$, the total number of permutations, and $P$, the number of palindromic permutations, then we can calculate  the number of permutations which do and don't dominate their reverse as follows.
For every non-palindromic permutation $\pi$, either $\pi$ will dominate its reverse $\pi^R$ or $\pi^R$ will dominate $\pi$. This is because lexicographic order is a total order. And a palindromic permutation will never dominate its reverse, which is itself. So there are $(N-P)/2$ permutations which dominate their reverse and $N - (N-P)/2 = (N+P)/2$ permutations which don't.

Now to compute $P$:

Suppose $n_i$ is odd. Then $i$ must appear in the center position. This because for every time $i$ appears before the middle, it must also appear once after, so the number of times it appears outside the center is even.

So if more than one $n_i$ is odd, this means $P = 0$.

If exactly one $n_i$ is odd, then let $n'_1 = n_1/2$, etc. except for $n_i$ we round down: $n'_i = \lfloor n'_i/2 \rfloor$. Then exactly $n'_j$ copies of $j$ must appear in the front half, in any order. Let $n' = n'_1 + \cdots + n'_k$. So we have $P = \frac{n'!}{n'_1!n'_2!\cdots n'_k!}$.

If all of the $n_i$ are even, then do the same, but you don't need to round down.



Thanks so much for the answer.  Do you have a reference for your answer?  Do you also happen to know of an algorithm that allows us to enumerate the subset of permutations that do not dominate their reverse.

I came up with this one my own @RaymondKan. As for the second question, I don't know.
